# select most selled products in range with one query?

Tags: laravel

Is it possible to select most selled products in range with one query?
Here tables :

**orders** table with columns(id,created_at,paid)

**order_products**(order_id,product_id)

**products**(id,title)

I tried this but it isn't working

```
\App\Models\Order::with('order_products')->where('paid',1)
        ->whereBetween('created_at',[$request->to,$request->from])
        ->orderBy(\DB::raw('count(order_products.product_id)'))->get());
```

Answer (score 0):

presuming every order_products represent selling one product item, you could do it using left join and traditional group by:

```
  $mostSalledPrducts = Product::query()
        ->leftJoin('order_products','products.id','=','order_products.product_id')
        ->join('orders','orders.id','=','order_products.order_id')
        ->where('orders.paid',1)
        ->selectRaw('products.*, COALESCE(count(order_products.id),0) total')
        ->groupBy('products.id')
        ->orderBy('total','desc')
        ->take(5)
        ->get();
```